# How to place tikz pic text inside angle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I am wanting to position the text '0.78' within my angle rather than on the outer perimeter of it. Also, I am wanting to see the line that is covered by the yellow fill. This is my code so far, where am I going wrong? Thank you for your help

```
 % ray on rim edge
\coordinate (A) at (7,7);
\coordinate (B) at (7,3.45254);

    % incident ray
    \draw[black!60!white,line width=0.25,directed] (A) -- (B);

    % ray - no errors
    \coordinate (C) at (0.09523861, 3.54684049);
    \draw[black!60!white,line width=0.25,tube] (B) -- (C);

    %ray - positive half-acceptance
    \draw[line width=0.25, far, black!60!white, domain=7:0.00493732] plot(\x,{-0.02722281*(\x)+3.6434});

    %ray - negative half-acceptance
    \coordinate (D) at (0.00493732, 3.45283808);
    \draw[black!60!white,line width=0.25,far] (B) -- (D);     

\coordinate(X) at (0.00493732,3.6434);

\path (X)--(B)--(D) pic[draw=orange, <->, ,angle eccentricity=1.05, angle radius=6cm, font=\tiny, fill=yellow!20!white, pic text = 0.78$^{\circ}$]{angle = X--B--D};
```

Comment: Please provide us with a `complete` minimal working example. Starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. And loading all `packages`, `libraries` and, in you case `.style` definitons.

Answer (score 3):

You have to draw the objects in the correct order.  To have the label to the right of the angle, some trickery is needed, because the label is placed on the left by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  directed/.style={},
  tube/.style={},
  far/.style={},
  ]
  % ray on rim edge
  \coordinate (A) at (7,7);
  \coordinate (B) at (7,3.45254);
  \coordinate (C) at (0.09523861, 3.54684049);
  \coordinate (D) at (0.00493732, 3.45283808);
  \coordinate (X) at (0.00493732,3.6434);

  % incident ray
  \draw[black!60!white,line width=0.25,directed] (A) -- (B);

  % ray - no errors
  \draw[black!60!white,line width=0.25,tube] (B) -- (C);

  \path (X)--(B)--(D) pic[draw=orange, <->, ,angle eccentricity=1.05, angle radius=6cm, font=\tiny, fill=yellow!20!white, pic text = $0.78^{\circ}$, pic text options={right=.3cm}]{angle = X--B--D};

  % ray - positive half-acceptance
  \draw[line width=0.25, far, black!60!white, domain=7:0.00493732] plot(\x,{-0.02722281*(\x)+3.6434});

  % ray - negative half-acceptance
  \draw[black!60!white,line width=0.25,far] (B) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]